# Select radio button by text

Tags: html, xpath

I have a radio button:

```
<input type="radio">test</input>
```

and I would like to retrieve the element by XPath using through its type and the text inside. I have tried the following:

```
//input[@type='radio' and text() = 'test']
```

but it hasn't worked out. I believe the problem is in the text() part since `//input[@type='radio']` does select the element.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML/XHTML, `input` is an empty element; it cannot contain text. In this case, the text `test` actually exists as a sibling text node that *directly follows* the `input` element node, rather than as a text node *within* the `input` element node. Consequently, the closing `</input>` tag you have there doesn't mean anything.

Try this instead:

```
//input[@type='radio' and following-sibling::text() = 'test']
```

Or this:

```
//input[@type='radio' and contains(following-sibling::text(), 'test')]
```

Comment: Yeah, the browser is ignoring the invalid `</input>` tag.  Yet another stupid result of the Netscape v. IE3 wars.